# SQL Server - Identify new entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the customers of a company are listed each month. If 4 new customers are added and none leaves, there would thus be added 4 more rows to the table, than what was added the month before. I thought I could identify these 4 new customers by the following code, but it returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT Variable1
FROM   Table1
WHERE  DateVariable = 201311
       AND Variable1 NOT IN (SELECT Variable1
                             FROM   Table1
                             WHERE  DateVariable < 201311)
```

What is the problem with my query?

Comment: Your query will return all rows from Table1 where the DateVariable equals 201311, except those rows with the same Variable1 where the DateVariable is less than 201311. There does not seem to be anything wrong with your query. Can you tell us a bit more about how your data is structured?

Comment: What happens if the customer leaves? Do you delete him from the database?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could explain why he did it.  I see nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Each month a list of the customers are added to the datatable, old customers included, but an appropriate datestamp is added to the entry. If I had 100customers by October, but got an additional 4, then I would add 104 lines to my table in November. I am trying to extract only the 4 new customers. In my code, I try to get all the customerID's with a datestamp of 201311, but excluding those that exist in the dataset, from before 201311. In my mind, that should give me only the new entries, but this is where I tihnk I may be wrong, as I am not experienced at all with how to do such a query.

Comment: @user3099431 - No need to add "Solved". Simply accepting an answer (as you have done) marks it as solved.

Comment: What is the datatype of `DateVariable` anyway though? `201311` is an integer not a date.

Comment: Yeah it's basically just an integer, but I think the logic would've been the same, if it had been an actual datevariable, but I could be and probably am wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an attempt to answer your question.  This is a demonstration of how to make your query run faster.

While intuitive and database agnostic, this construct,

```
where somefield not in (subquery goes here)
```

is slow.  Here is something that has the same logic as your query, but will run faster.

```
SELECT Variable1
FROM Table1
WHERE DateVariable = 201311 

except

SELECT Variable1
FROM Table1
WHERE DateVariable <201311
```

In some databases, Oracle for example, the keyword is "minus" instead of except.  There are probably some databases that don't support this construct at all.  However, you are using sql server, which does.

Comment: Well. That answered it and I believe that gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your answer :) I don't know how to give you plus or up-vote or anything, but I would surely like to.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your DateVariable? Is it a date with a default value = GetDate()?

You should probably try with a DateVariable >= '201311

Your not in, has no sense, as you are asking for =, you don't need a not in <, it's already done.

Can you show some line from your table, like one you don't want to show and one you would like

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, since pieces of information are missing.

However, this is how you would output all customers, who are new in this month:

```
SELECT Variable1
FROM Table1
WHERE DateVariable >= '20131201'
```

If you need to check last month's customers, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT Variable1
FROM Table1
WHERE DateVariable < '20131201' AND DateVariable >= '20131101'
```

Comment: In my table, the list of customers are represented 1 time every month. So if there were 100 customers in October, there would be 100new lines added to the dataset. If November brought 4 additional customers, then there would be added 104 lines to the table for November. My query is to extract only the 4 newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT #fields
FROM   #Table
WHERE  #field = 201311 --(Variable1)
AND    Variable1 NOT IN (
         SELECT #fields
         FROM   #Table
         WHERE  DateVariable < 201311 /* will give you new customers*/
)
```